# How to pre-populate JavaScript forms in ArcGIS Web Application?

Tags: arcgis-server, javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I have an ArcGIS web application and would like to pre-populate order numbers.  Say if order 1 has been entered for a point on a map, when the next point is added, order 2 would populate automatically.  Of course these numbers are a series of letters and numbers, say abcd1234, next order would automatically populate abcd12345.  I am using SQL server to submit new features with feature access capabilities.  The web application is using the JavaScript API.  I have the code hosted on an IIS web server in order to access the actual JavaScript.